# Parsing html from google with python

Tags: python, html

I have problems with parsing the html source from google with python

```
def events():
    location = sys.argv[1];
    url = "https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=evenementen+" + location;
    event = requests.get(url=url)
        print("De zoekterm is leeg, probeer het opnieuw")
    soup_events = BeautifulSoup(event.text, 'html.parser')
    events_google = soup_events.find_all('<a class="rl_item rl_item_base" tabindex="0" href="/search?client=firefox-b-d')
    print(type(events_google))
    print(len(events_google))
    print(events_google)
```

I tried:
    `events_google = soup_events.find_all('div', 'BNeawe tAd8D AP7Wnd')`
    Which worked but when i try any other value it outputs 0
But all values that i want to print out show up when i try to print the event.text
i'm not sure what im doing wrong.
When I run the code above i get the following response:

```
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
0
[]
```

I'm actually looking to find the events shown in a google search.

Comment: could you post a smaller example (please remove the location-parsing stuff and just give us a value for "location" that illustrates the issue)?  Also, an example of something that you're searching for, and can't find, would help a lot.

Comment: I will remove the location parsing and the example of something i'm searching for is at the bottom of the code. i'll provide more details in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

ahhh, I think your issue is

```
events_google = soup_events.find_all('<a class="rl_item rl_item_base" tabindex="0" href="/search?client=firefox-b-d')
```

should be

```
events_google = soup_events.find_all("a", 
        {"class" : ["r1_item", " r1_item_base"]})
```

Comment: does `soup_events.find_all("a")` show anything useful?  (I can't see your underlying HTML, so it's a bit hard to debug `find()` commands for you.)